# ヘルプ センターで使用されているスクリーンショットを最新のものに替えたい

Tags: 機能の要求, 対応予定, ヘルプ

### 提案内容

幾つかのヘルプ センターの記事には、**掲載されているスクリーンショットが実際の見た目と異なっている**ものがあります。この状態はスタック・オーバーフローの使い方に困ったときに参照する資料として好ましくないため、新しいスクリーンショットに替えることを提案します。

---

### 影響範囲

私が確認した限りでは、ヘルプ センターで

- 画像に英語のテキストが含まれる。
- 画像で示されているスタック・オーバーフローの見た目が現在のものと異なる。

という二つの条件を満たしている記事は以下のとおりです。項目数が多いため、スニペットとして掲載しています。

```html
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics
```

---

### 新しい画像の提案

質問文に新しい画像の提案も載せたかったのですが、以下の理由から回答として投稿します。

- 想像するよりも対象となる記事の数が多く、質問文が長くなってしまう。
- 一部の記事について、信頼度が不足しておりスクリーンショットを撮影出来ず、不完全な提案になる。

Answer (score 3):

### 提案する新しい画像の一覧

- 切り取りが雑なので、余計なものがスクリーンショット内に入っていることがあります。
- 矢印や枠線による強調は今のところ行っていません。
- 画像の変更や文章の変更など、自由に編集してくださって構いません。

#### 別の質問をしようとするとシステムから1日以上待つように言われました。これはなぜですか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 興味のあるトピックはどうしたら見つかりますか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### アカウントの削除方法は？

この記事の内容全般を見直す必要がありそうなので、未掲載

#### メタへの参加

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### Wiki 投稿の作成

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 投稿の通報

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### お礼の設定

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 広告を減らす

スタック・オーバーフローでは投稿内に広告が表示されないので、未掲載

#### クローズ票の表示

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### クローズ票および再オープンの投票

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 確立したユーザー

実際の動作と異なる説明があるため、未掲載

#### タグの別名の作成

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### タグ Wiki 編集の承認

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### モデレーター ツールへのアクセス

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### アクセス解析の閲覧

信用度不足のため、未掲載

Answer (score 0):

大変お待たせしてしまい申し訳ございませんが、これら4ページにつきましては現在新しいスクリーンショットの準備を進めており、近日中に差し替えられる予定です。

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited
  （差し替え予定）

[image: 2024年現在のスクリーンショット]

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics
  翻訳案  [ヘルプセンター：「興味のあるトピックはどうしたら見つかりますか？」を改善したい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4037/14055)
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

CM での編集が不可能な以下の権限ページについては、現在編集方法を模索しています。

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics

おそれいりますが、何卒ご理解いただけますようお願い申し上げます‍♀️。