# サイトの未翻訳箇所を見つけて、もくもく会で直しましょう

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳, 交流会

令和2年2月22日(土)の13時より、オンラインでスタック・オーバーフローもくもく会が開かれます。

質問や回答をしたりメタの投稿を充実させたりと皆さんのやりたいことをする会にしようと思っていますが、やれることが見つからなくて参加しにくい場合もあるでしょう。というか私が悩んでました。

何かないかと考えていると、ひとつ手をつけやすいタスクとして、未翻訳箇所の和訳をするのは面白いかもな、と思いました。最近の UI 改善によって未翻訳箇所が増えていることもあり、良く使われているのに翻訳されていない場所がまだ残っているかもしれません。

**そこで皆さんにお願いです：皆さんが気付いた未翻訳箇所を教えてください！**　[Traducir](https://ja.traducir.win/) を見れば何が未翻訳かは分かるのですが、その英語がサイトのどこで使われているのかが分からず、翻訳しにくいという問題があります。またユーザーによって表示されたり表示されなかったりするものもあります。

こんな感じで投稿いただければな、と思います。

- ひとつの回答にひとつの未翻訳箇所。
- スクリーンショットと、可能であれば URL があると文脈が分かりやすいです。
- 「ここは翻訳して欲しい！」という回答はプラス投票して頂けると優先度がつけられます。
- 既にメタに挙がっているものでも再掲 OK です！

よろしくお願いします！

<sub>※いっぱい集まりすぎるともくもく会だけで直し切れないかもしれませんが、その場合は残ったものを TODO として別にメタへ投稿して後に引き継ごうかなと思っています。</sub>

<sub>※もちろん、もくもく会までに直せそうなら直していただいて構いません！　その際回答へのコメントで直ったことをお知らせいただけるとありがたいです。</sub>

---

### 追記

もくもく会が終わりました！　もくもく会までの間に翻訳されたものも、もくもく会中に翻訳されたものも、まだ翻訳が終わっていないものもあります。

未翻訳のものについてはそれぞれ個別のメタ投稿として私が投稿しなおしておきました。今後翻訳されると良いなと思います。

もくもく会の終了に伴い、こちらの投稿自体は [完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86) といたします。みなさまありがとうございました。

Comment: 関連: [ヘルプ センターで使用されているスクリーンショットを最新のものに替えたい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3204)

Answer (score 3):

[Moderator Agreement (モデレーター契約)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement)

- ページタイトルのみ「モデレーターアグリーメント」になっている。
- 万人が読むとは限らないかもしれないが、モデレーターに興味を持った人が目を通すかもしれないので。

Comment: このページは法律・規約が関わってきそうなページなので、念の為翻訳しても良いものなのか伺いを立てる質問をしてみました: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3224/19110

Comment: このページは翻訳できません。詳しくは上のコメントでリンクしている投稿に書きましたのでご覧ください。

Answer (score 3):

「プロフィールを削除」ページの文章はすべて未翻訳の状態で残っています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: もくもく会が終わったので、こちらに個別の投稿をいたしました。ご報告ありがとうございました！（他のご投稿にも同じようなコメントをするので通知がうるさいかもしれません、ご容赦くださいませ）　https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3264/19110

Answer (score 2):

お問合せの文章が未翻訳です（しかもこの string は Traducir にありません）。

https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact

> [image]

Comment: 「トピックを選択してください」という選択ボックスにも未翻訳箇所があるのですが、こちらは ja.traducir.win に文字列が存在します。

Comment: もくもく会が終わったのでこちらに分離しました https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3265/19110

Answer (score 2):

ヘルプセンター > 質問にあたって > [How to Ask Questions in Private Beta](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta) (ページ全体)

---

追記@2020/2/22　
反映済み（翻訳案は[こちら](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3238/14055)）

Comment: このヘルプはページの内容自体が現状にそぐわないため翻訳が保留された経緯があります。[この投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2941/19110)や[こちらの投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2942/19110)で議論されました。とはいえ、機会があるときにえいやと翻訳してしまうのは良いかもしれません。

Comment: みなさん、えいやと背中を押してくださってありがとうございます m_ _m。一歩前に進みまして、本ページは2/22のもくもく会までに反映されるかもしれません

Answer (score 2):

["タグの別名 (シノニム)" 一覧ページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)

- 上記ページ以外でも「タグ シノニム」「タグの別名」が混在しているので、「(タグの)別名」に揃える。

**関連:**
[用語の変更：「タグシノニム」を「タグの別名」に変えませんか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1851)

Comment: もくもく会が終わったので、こちらに個別の投稿をいたしました: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3267/19110

Answer (score 2):

[検索条件を示す文字列の一部](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D%20%22javascript%22)が未翻訳になっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: [該当の String](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/4531) 及び関連する文字列をそれぞれ翻訳しておきました。

Answer (score 2):

「メール設定」の「メール設定を編集」ページの下部に未翻訳箇所があります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

追記@2020/2/22　
翻訳完了です。

Answer (score 2):

[アカウントの登録](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/signup)ページのチェックボックスの文字列が未翻訳となっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

追記@2020/2/22　
翻訳完了です。

Answer (score 2):

コメントの通報理由に関する文字列が未翻訳となっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

追記@2020/2/22　
翻訳完了です。

Answer (score 2):

通報履歴の「役に立つ」、「却下済み」、「レビュー待ち」のときに表示される見出しとその直下のボックスの文字列が未翻訳となっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: もくもく会が終わったので、こちらに新しく投稿いたしました。ご報告ありがとうございました！　https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3266/19110

Answer (score 1):

「レビューキュー」の説明。現状では MSE の投稿へのリンクになっている。

- [質問が [クローズ済み] または [改善待ち] とは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

  > **[クローズ済み] とマークされている質問があるのはなぜですか？**
  >
  > ... 自動的に [レビュー キュー](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues) におかれ ...
- [レビューキューへのアクセス](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)

  > ... これらおよび [その他すべてのレビュー キュー](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues) は、...

Comment: もくもく会が終わったので、こちらに個別の投稿をいたしました https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3268/19110

Answer (score 1):

[Markdown 編集ヘルプ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)の一部テキストが未翻訳の状態になっています。複数存在するためスクリーンショットではなく ja.traducir.win の URL を載せておきます。

- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/74
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/4237
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/3124
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/5215
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/3639
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/5189
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/902
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/143
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/8567
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/4742
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/5668
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/6950

Comment: 載せられていた string すべてについて、何かしら翻訳が送られた状態になっていました。

Answer (score 1):

タイムラインのイベントフィルターに関する文字列が未翻訳となっています ([例](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3200/timeline))。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

追記@2020/2/22　
翻訳完了です。

Answer (score 1):

[以前の回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3216/32986)と同様に、簡易版 Markdown 編集ヘルプにも未翻訳箇所があります。以下のスクリーンショットは、その一部です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: もくもく会が終わったので、こちらに投稿を分離しました。ご報告ありがとうございました！　https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3269/19110