# 英語が残っている：Moderator Agreement

Tags: バグ, 却下, 翻訳

モデレーターアグリーメント https://ja.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement が HTML の `title` を除いて英語のままになっています。モデレーターに興味がある方が読みやすいよう、翻訳したいです。

- このページを翻訳しても良いですか？　URL に legal と含まれているので少し心配しています。
- 翻訳して良いなら、回答として和訳を投稿するので反映したいです。

<sub>補足：この投稿は[別のご投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3212/19110)から派生して個別に投稿したものです。</sub>

---

To SE Team:

I would like to translate [Moderator Agreement](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) into Japanese in order to make it easier to read for potential moderators.

- Is it OK to trasnlate this page?
- Could you update the page after the translation is complete?

Comment: 当該内容に関する議題と思われる投稿が[ロシア版](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2109)および[スペイン版](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3486)の Stack Overflow で見つかりました。翻訳機にかけて読んでみたところ、どうやらどちらのメタ投稿も「翻訳は出来ない」という結論で落ち着いているようです。

Answer (score 4):

このページは現状翻訳できません。

モデレーターアグリーメントはモデレーターと Stack Exchange 社との間の契約が書かれている法的な文書であり、これを英語以外で書いたとするとそれが妥当なものであるかどうか判断できる法務の社員が現状いないため、翻訳が提案されても反映することができないとのことです。今日 Nicolas さんに[確認しました](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53267016#53267016)。