# ヘルプセンターの「信用度とモデレーション」に未翻訳のヘルプがある

Tags: サポート, 翻訳, ヘルプ

表題のとおり[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)の信用度とモデレーションに英語の項目が2点存在します。

- [Moderator Agreement policies](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mod-agreement-policies)
- [Who are the staff, and what is their role here?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/staff)

Comment: Moderator Agreement に関しては過去にも議題に挙がりましたが、他のヘルプと違って法的な文書となり翻訳後の検証が難しいので [翻訳しない (できない) という結論に至っています。](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3226)

Comment: Moderator Agreement policies 自体は `/help/` 配下にあるもので、 `/legal/` 配下にある Moderator Agreement と同様の扱いとなるのかは明らかではないと思います。スペイン語版では [Moderator Agreement は翻訳されず](https://es.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement)、 [Moderator Agreement policies は翻訳されています](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mod-agreement-policies)。

Comment: 両方とも、翻訳案をいただければモデレーターかスタッフの権限で編集できるんじゃないかなと思います。

Answer (score 3):

[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

[Who are the staff, and what is their role here?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/staff)の翻訳案です。

## スタッフとは誰で、どんな役割を担っていますか？

---

スタッフとは、スタック・オーバーフロー（Stack Exchange, Inc.）でさまざまな業務をこなす従業員です。スタッフは被雇用者でありボランティアではありません。サイトに顔出ししているスタッフは [Community Management（コミュニティ管理）や Public Platform（共通基盤）チーム](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349266/the-community-teams-stack-exchange-and-how-we-work-together)に所属していることが多いですが、これらはプラットフォームを運用するスタッフ全体におけるほんの一つの部署にすぎません。

### スタッフを見分けるにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

スタッフはそれぞれマークが異なる2つの役割のいずれかに分類されます：

- General staff（一般スタッフ）- このメンバーは大多数の従業員を代表します。ふだんは一般のユーザです。Metaサイトでこの人たちが活動した際には、投稿やコメントにスタッフラベルが表示され、Metaのプロフィールにはスタッフのマークが付与されています。
- Diamond staff（ダイヤモンド スタッフ）- モデレーションツールやコンテンツへの特権アクセスを必要とするスタッフです。その多くは開発、設計、コミュニティチームのメンバーです。彼らはより明確な形でユーザ名の横にダイヤモンド◆を表示します。これは[選挙によるモデレータ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)と同様です。このメンバーは「`◆モデレータ`」と「`スタッフ`」タグの両方がプロフィールに付与されています。

Answer (score 1):

[Moderator Agreement policies](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mod-agreement-policies) の翻訳案はこちらにお願いいたします。

## モデレーターアグリーメントポリシー

---

モデレーターは以下の[アグリーメント](/legal/moderator-agreement)に合意する必要があります。

> (...)[モデレーター及びユーザーが]利用可能で公式にアナウンスされたすべてのモデレーター及びユーザーポリシーを遵守します。

Stack Exchange ネットワークには多数の FAQ（よくある質問）とコミュニティポリシーが存在しますが、本ステートメントは Stack Exchange Inc. によって定義されネットワーク全体で使用される一部のポリシーのみ適用されます。モデレーターアグリーメントが変更されることは比較的まれですが、モデレーターはアグリーメントが変更されるたびに再合意する必要があるためここにポリシーが記載されており、モデレーターアグリーメントとは別でポリシーが最新の状態に保たれます。これらのポリシーが変更、或いは新しくポリシーが追加される場合には、それらの変更がモデレーターに通知されます。

分かりやすくするためにこのヘルプ記事では[行動規範](/conduct)、[利用規約](/legal/terms-of-service)、[プライバシーポリシー](/legal/privacy-policy)を除く、モデレーターアグリーメントとは別に記載されている遵守する必要のある公式ポリシーを示します。

**Where can I find these policies?**

The referenced policies are currently found on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). All official policies on MSE will be tagged with [the [mod-agreement-policy] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mod-agreement-policy), which is a staff-only tag, and will have a policy lock applied. It is possible that policies may appear in other places such as the help center or blog. If that happens, links will be added to this page so that they can be easily found.

**When and how are new policies introduced by Stack Exchange, Inc.?**

If the need for a new policy arises, it will be written and shared with the [Moderator Council](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347104/introducing-the-moderator-council-and-its-first-pro-tempore-representatives) first. Then, it will pass through a process of feedback and possible iterations before being presented to the moderators on their Team. These future policies will then be posted on MSE and receive the [mod-agreement-policy] tag to denote their status.

**Is a policy missing, or not relevant any more?**

Sometimes a policy tagged on MSE or contained in the list above is no longer relevant — maybe a new one that replaces it came up, or something else changed that makes it obsolete. Sometimes there's something that's a good candidate for being included in the list but isn't yet. In either case, contact a CM in the [Teachers' Lounge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/teachers-lounge) so we can chat about how to proceed. If you're not a moderator, raise a flag on the post and one of the MSE mods will get our attention.

**Is this tag meant to encompass all policies and rules?**

No. This is not intended to be seen as a rulebook. The vast majority of rules and policies on the network are community-defined and company supported. Those policies often vary by site and may not apply to some sites at all. Additionally, many of the policies you find are "best practices" determined through years of experience as a Q&A platform.

While we support these policies, they do not reach the degree where we consider following them to be part of the Moderator Agreement. The tag will be used only on policies that Moderators are agreeing to abide by and enforce in their communities, when applicable.