# アカウント削除ページが未翻訳

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

プロフィールページの「アカウントを削除」を押すとたどり着ける「プロフィールを削除」ページ `https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/delete/<id>` が未翻訳のままです。

[image]

Traducir に該当 string があるようなので、これらを翻訳すれば良さそうです。

例: https://ja.traducir.win/strings/7879

---

※この投稿は、supa さんの[こちらの投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3218/19110)から分離したものです。

Answer (score 3):

該当の string にひととおり和訳を送りました。確認ステップを経た後、和訳が反映されるはずです。