# お問合せの文章が未翻訳

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

お問合せの文章が未翻訳です（しかもこの string は Traducir にありません）。

https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact

> [image]

また、「トピックを選択してください」という選択ボックスにも未翻訳箇所があるのですが、こちらは ja.traducir.win に文字列が存在します。

---

※この投稿は、私の[こちらの投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3210/19110)から分離したものです。