# 通報履歴の見出しが未翻訳

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

通報履歴の「役に立つ」、「却下済み」、「レビュー待ち」のときに表示される見出しとその直下のボックスの文字列が未翻訳となっています。

[image]
[image]
[image]

Traducir に string があるようなので、これを翻訳すれば良さそうです。

例: https://ja.traducir.win/strings/10658

---

※この投稿は、supa さんの[こちらの投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3222/19110)から分離したものです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「役に立つ」と「却下済み」は以下の通り反映されましたことを確認しました。

[image: 役に立つ]
[image: 却下された]

Pendingのストリングは[こちら](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/10663)で、反映されております。

Comment: 通報の結果は "過去" の情報なので、「却下された/却下済み」に合わせて「役に立つ」も『役に立った』の方がより自然かなとも思いました。

Comment: 確かにそうですね ♪ "helpful"のストリングは沢山あるのですが、まずは通報履歴には『役に立った』が表示されるように変更してまいりますね。