# レビューキューの説明へのリンク先を改善したい

Tags: 討議, 翻訳

いくつかのページの「レビューキュー」の説明についているリンクが、現状では MSE の投稿へのリンクになっています。日本語にしたいです。

- [質問が [クローズ済み] または [改善待ち] とは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

  > **[クローズ済み] とマークされている質問があるのはなぜですか？**
  >
  > ... 自動的に [レビュー キュー](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues) におかれ ...
- [レビューキューへのアクセス](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)

  > ... これらおよび [その他すべてのレビュー キュー](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues) は、...

---

この投稿は、cubick さんの[こちらの投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3214/19110)から分離したものです。