# 簡易 Markdown ヘルプが未翻訳

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

質問を投稿する画面で「？」ボタンを押すと出てくる簡易版 Markdown 編集ヘルプに未翻訳箇所があります。以下のスクリーンショットは、その一部です。

[image]

いくつかは Traducir に string があるようですが、右上の "Advanced help" は無いようです。

---

この投稿は、supa さんの[こちらの投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3227/19110)から分離したものです。

Comment: "Advanced help" に関しては、MSE でも既に要望が出ています - [Add string “Advanced help” into transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344068)