# ヘルプセンター：「興味のあるトピックはどうしたら見つかりますか？」を改善したい

Tags: サポート, 翻訳, ヘルプ

この投稿は、[興味のあるトピックはどうしたら見つかりますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics)の改善案です。(英語の原文は[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics))

supa さんが[ご提案くださったスクリーンショット](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3205/14055)に差し替えたいと思います‍♀️。その他にも改善できる箇所があれば編集やコメントをお願いします。

---

興味のある特定の質問を見つけるには、いくつかの方法があります。

### タグでブラウズ

このサイトに投稿されるすべての質問には、主要なトピックを表す[タグ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)が付けられています。特定のトピックに関する質問を見つけるには、[タグページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags)にアクセスして人気のあるタグを参照するか、特定のタグを検索してください。

サイトのどこからでも（タグページや質問の下のタグから）タグをクリックすると、そのタグが含まれるすべての質問のリストが表示されます。そのリストを、新着やアクティブという順に並べ替えたり、回答なしの質問のみにフィルタリングすることができます。

各タグには、[タグ Wiki の要約](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts)が含まれており、サイトでそのタグを使用する場合の簡単なガイダンスが書かれています。この要約は、タグページの上部、タグページのタグ名の下、およびサイト上の任意の場所でタグの上にマウスを移動すると現れるポップオーバーに表示されます。また、各タグには、そのトピックをより詳細に紹介するタグ Wiki の本文もあります。

特定のタグ内で新しいアクティビティ通知を受け取るには、タグの上にマウスをかざして表示される、ポップオーバーの右上にあるオレンジ色の RSS フィードアイコンをクリックして RSS 経由で購読することができます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### タグを検索

複数のトピックに関する質問を探している場合は、タグで[検索](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search)することもできます。検索では、検索演算子 `OR` だけでなく、括弧で囲まれたタグ (`[タグ]` など) も認識されます。デフォルトの演算子は `AND` です。すなわち、`[タグ1] [タグ2]` で検索すると両方のタグがついた投稿のみが返されます。いずれかのタグでマークされた質問を検索するには、 検索に `OR` を挿入します (例：`[タグ1] or [タグ2]`など)。

タグで検索する場合、タグ内でワイルドカードとしてアスタリスク (`*`) を使用することもできます (例: [`タグ*`])。このような検索は、一致するタグの `OR` 検索に自動的に変換されます。例えば、[`python*`] を検索すると、python で始まりその `python タグ`を持つすべての結果が (例: `[python] or [python2] or [python3]`) などのように変換され表示されます。

検索語が 単一のタグの場合 (例: 単に[`タグ`] と検索した場合)、通常の検索を行うのではなく、そのタグのページに移動します。さらに、検索語がサイト上で最もよく使用されている 40 のタグの名前と一致する場合も、同様にそのタグのページに移動します。

検索の使用に関するヒントについては、ヘルプセンターの[検索の方法は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)をご覧ください。以下の Meta Stack Exchange の FAQ (英語) も参照してください。

- [How do I search for questions with (or without) specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5229/314875)
- [Filtering questions by multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17003/314875)

### ウォッチしているタグと無視するタグの追加

興味のない質問をフィルタリングして、関心のある質問に絞り込むもう 1 つの方法は、ウォッチしているタグと無視するタグを追加することです。

**ウォッチしているタグ** (以前は「お気に入りタグ」と呼ばれていました) は、重要で興味深い質問を呼び出すためのものです。ウォッチしているタグが付けられた質問は、ホームページと質問リストでハイライトされます。

**無視するタグ**は興味のないトピックに関する質問を目立たなく非表示にします。デフォルトでは、これらのタグが含まれる質問は、ホームページやサイト上の他の質問リストではグレーに表示されますが、引き続き表示されます。(または、以下で説明するように、これらの質問を完全に非表示にすることもできます。)

ウォッチまたは無視するタグを追加するには、いくつかの異なる方法があります。

1. 最も簡単な方法は、タグの上にカーソルを合わせて、「タグをウォッチ」または「タグを無視」をクリックすることです。（対応するボタンをもう一度クリックすると、ウォッチ解除または無視解除することもできます。）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

2. あるいは、サイトのホームにアクセスし、右側のサイドバーにある「ウォッチしているタグ」と「無視するタグ」セクションを見つけて、タグをウォッチ / 無視することもできます。

[image: @supaさんからの画像]

ウォッチしているタグ又は無視するタグを追加するとここにリストされ、対応するボックスの右上に「編集」ボタンが表示されます。

ここから、無視するタグを使用して質問を完全に非表示にすることもできます。これを行うには、[無視するタグ] の見出しの横にある [編集] をクリックし、[無視するタグが付いた質問を非表示] オプションを選択します。(同じプロセスに従い、[無視するタグが付いた質問をグレー表示] を選択することで、いつでもこれを元に戻すことができます。)

[image: 無視するタグ]

3. 最後に、ユーザープロフィールの「設定」タブにある「タグのウォッチと無視」ページに移動することで、ウォッチしているタグと無視するタグを管理することもできます。

[image: タグのウォッチ]

上記の 2. や 3. のいずれかを利用して、ウォッチまたは無視されるタグにワイルドカードとしてアスタリスクを使用することもできます。( つまり、ホームの右側サイドバーから、または設定から操作します。) 例えば、`テスト` という用語を含むすべてのタグをウォッチまたは無視したい場合は、ウォッチ / 無視したいタグを指定するときに、単に `*テスト*` と入力します。

ウォッチしているタグと無視するタグの詳細については、以下の Meta Stack Exchange の FAQ (英語) をご参照ください : [What do "watched tags" and "ignored tags" do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173/314875)

### タグで質問リストをフィルタリングする

カスタムフィルタを使用すると、特定の基準を満たす質問のカスタマイズされたリストを表示できます。タグによるフィルタリング機能も含まれます。また、これらのカスタムフィルタを保存し、後にアクセスできるようにすることも可能です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

タグでフィルタリングするには、指定したタグを持つ質問のみにリストをフィルタリングするか、ウォッチしているタグのいずれかを持つ質問にフィルタリングするかを選択できます。指定したタグでフィルタリングする場合、タグを指定する際にワイルドカードとしてアスタリスクを使用することができます (タグで検索する際と同様です)。また、1 つのフィルタに複数のタグを含める場合は、タグ間に `OR` 演算子を追加して、指定したタグのいずれかを持つ質問を返すことができます (それ以外の場合、すべての指定したタグを持つ質問のみがデフォルトとして表示されます)。

カスタムフィルタの使用方法の詳細については、MSE の FAQ (英語) をご参照ください: [Custom Filters release announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330326/314875)

---

タグに関するその他の質問がある場合、「タグ付け」セクションにリンクされた MSE の FAQ (英語) をご参照ください: [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/314875)